# Equality of unicode chars

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I need to write a simple comparison.

```
if (user entered "Д" first)
{
   //do something
}
```

The problem is that I need to compare the Unicode characters (in this case, the Russian letter "Д").

I managed to do this in the following way:

```
std::string option;
getline(std::cin, option);
if (option.compare(0, 1, u8"Д"))
{
   //do something
}
```

How can I do this with char, without using `std::string` with `compare`? Although I would be happy if you offered a better solution for `std::string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far from ideal, but it simple and works (I hope):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char const yes[] = u8"Д";
char const no[] = u8"Н";

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    while (std::cin >> str)
    {

        std::cout << "Let's Да? " << str << "! => " << std::boolalpha << (str.substr(0, sizeof(yes) - 1) == yes) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Let's Нет? " << str << "! => " << std::boolalpha << (str.substr(0, sizeof(no) - 1) == no) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Vhtl1T

```
Let's Да? Да! => true
Let's Нет? Да! => false
Let's Да? Нет! => false
Let's Нет? Нет! => true
Let's Да? Нет! => false
Let's Нет? Нет! => true
Let's Да? Да! => true
Let's Нет? Да! => false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer and the comment of Barmak Shemirani helped me a lot.